# Append List when user goes to the last list in a view SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i am a newbie in IOS development, so I wanted to do something like when the user scroll and reaches the bottom of the list, the list updates and append it data. basically an infinite scrolling.

But I have no idea other than setting it via engineering the offset, it would take a lot of time and effort + might not be that clean/brilliant solution. Are there any other solution other than using a 3rd person library?

Thank you

here's my code :

```
ForEach(homeContent.MainContent){data in
                        homeContentItem(name: data.name ?? "", image: data.image ?? "",  released: data.released ?? "")
                           .padding(.horizontal)
                           .onAppear{
                                 homeContent.appendData(currentItem: data)
                                }
                        }
```

What this code does is well infinite scrolling, but it'll always update and that is something that I don't want to, I want it when user scroll to the bottom first in order to update the list

Note : if there any similar question, please do comment it so that I could delete this one I guess

Comment: Good tutorial on this: https://www.donnywals.com/implementing-an-infinite-scrolling-list-with-swiftui-and-combine/

Comment: i actually follow that tutorial also, and that happened

Answer (score 0):

You were close with `onAppear`, you only missing checking index of item. You need to append new data only when last element is visible, not for anyone. I suggest you using `ForEachIndexed`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    var items = (0...100).map { _ in Item() }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEachIndexed(items) { i, item in
                    Text("\(i) \(item.id)")
                        .onAppear {
                            if i == items.indices.last {
                                items += (0...10).map { _ in Item() }
                                print("new items added", i, items.count)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ForEachIndexed<Data: RandomAccessCollection, Content: View, ID: Hashable>: View {
    let data: [EnumeratedSequence<Data>.Element]
    let content: (Int, Data.Element) -> Content
    let id: KeyPath<EnumeratedSequence<Data>.Element, ID>
    
    init(_ data: Data, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int, Data.Element) -> Content) where Data.Element: Identifiable, ID == Data.Element.ID {
        self.data = Array(data.enumerated())
        self.content = content
        self.id = \.element.id
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data, id: id) { element in
            content(element.offset, element.element)
        }
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    
    init() {
        id = UUID().uuidString
    }
}
```

Comment: what does i stand for?

Comment: @Farhandika How exactly it doesn't work? Have you copied all the code? This is just a sample. It's expected to show a list or random unique strings initially of count 100, and grow as far as you scroll. You can check if it's something you're looking for and then adapt it to your data.

Comment: i tried to use your code, like all of it without editing it. well it work but not what I imagined. it keeps adding new stuff to the list, just like my previous one. i tried to use it using my codes, well it's the same thing. i don't have to go to the end of the list to add new item to the list

Comment: @Farhandika This means I didn't understand you correctly, "when the user scroll and reaches the bottom of the list, the list updates and append it data". Could you explain what you mean by that? Sounds like exactly what I did.

Comment: @Farhandika for some reason in your code you're adding item which just appeared again to your list, is this something you wanna do? Add same items from the list to loop it?

Comment: so what you code did is everytime the view is built/shown, it append the data. what I want is when the user scroll and then reach the bottom of the list, then the list append

Comment: @Farhandika that's not true. By checking `if i == items.indices.last {` I'm adding new items only when the last item appears. You can check out the console as I've added a print